# Did the dialogue with "the Woman at the Well" forecast, by anticipation, Jesus's prophecy about the Destruction of the Temple in Matthew 24?

Tags: john, history, temple, olivet-discourse, worship

**Startling Statement** Within the conversation with the Woman at the Well, Jesus made this astounding statement:

*Believe Me, woman, a time is coming when you will worship the Father neither in this mountain nor in Jerusalem!* (John 4:21)

Was Jesus revealing to her what He would later announce to the Disciple in the Olivet Discourse: the **Temple** at Jerusalem would be destroyed, obsolete, passe'?

He also mentioned **this Mountain** which we know from archaeology and history, contained the Samaritan Temple. Its ruins were discovered by archaeologists. And it was destroyed during the Roman invasion, just before the Jewish Temple was destroyed in 70 A.D.

The real worship God was (is) interested in is *in spirit and in truth* (vs. 23-24):  A spiritual worship from the heart without need of any physical trappings, or sacerdotal accoutrements. This was good news to her...but would be startling to the disciples later, as judging by their questioning!

Is this one of many, the *first* of many, pronouncements Jesus would make about the End of the Old Testament covenants, and the institution of the New Covenant by the destruction of the Center of Worship of the Jews? Or was Jesus just speaking allegorically or metaphorically? (Luke 13:34-35, 16:16, 20:9-19, Matthew 8:11-13, Mark 12:1-12) Was Jesus just trying to pacify her racial prejudices? Or did He have a more concrete proposition in mind?

Comment: This question is a pandora's box and many books have been written.  The answer depends on one's (usually very fixed) presupposition concerning covenant theology.  The simplest answer is that Jesus was moving people away from liturgical ritual to true worship "in spirit and truth".

Comment: I think you've alluded to the answer in your question. v23 speaks of a time when 'true worshippers' will worship in spirit and truth. That's the thrust of the dialogue, not destruction of temples, but their redundancy in the coming age.

Answer (score 0):

No. He must be referring to something else, because the Samaritans have continued to worship on Mt. Gerizim to this day. Moreover he does not mention a temple. Also, although many Jews were expelled from Jerusalem when the temple was destroyed, others in Jerusalem found new ways of honoring God the that involved synagogue worship rather than temple sacrifices. There were [hundreds of such congregations in Jerusalem when the temple fell](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14160-synagogue). Despite mass slaughter, Josephus reports that [40,000 survived.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE)) Many became slaves but among these, some must have continued to worship there even if not publicly. Romans did not require their slaves to renounce their religion.

**The OP asks: Was Jesus just trying to pacify her racial prejudices?**

No. Moreover, racial prejudice ran mostly the other way. [Samaritans](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Samaritan) did not object to Judaism because of race but because Jews worshiped at Jerusalem instead of Gerizim. (They also believed that the Israelite priest Eli was an imposter, his Ark of the Covenant was a fake, and all of the kings of both Israel and Judah were illegitimate.)

**Or did He have a more concrete proposition in mind?**

Yes. He was referring to the idea that true worship does not require a temple at all.

> But the hour is coming, and is now here, when true
> worshipers will worship the Father in Spirit and truth; and indeed the
> Father seeks such people to worship him. (John 4:23)

**It is no accident that these words, which Christians apply generally, are delivered immediately after Jesus told the Samaritan woman that she (or the Samaritans) would worship neither at Gerizim nor Jerusalem. His prediction is not a forecast that either temple would be destroyed, but a prediction that he and his teaching would be accepted by both Jews and Samaritans. Moreover, this prediction was fulfilled in the many accounts in Acts of both Jews and Samaritans doing exactly that.**

Comment: **Clarification**-The Temple at Mt. Gerizim and the Temple at Jerusalem were both destroyed in the 67-70 War conflict (the first one by the Zealot rebels, and the second by the Romans.)  Both Samaritans and Jews still "worship", tis true, but without "the shedding of blood" (sacrifices), so there is no redemption accepted by God (See Hebrews 9:22).....Can we assume Jesus knew that the Temples would be destroyed?.....The Samaritans seemed to display prejudice when Jesus and the boys went through their village on the way to Jerusalem (Luke 9:51-56).

Comment: No. If he had been talking about blood sacrifices or destroyed temples he would have specified something about that. Instead, he immediately clarified that he was talking about worshiping "in spirit and in truth." This was already happening - "the hour is coming, and is now here." It was not a prediction of either temple's destruction but of a shift from worshiping centering on a certain place to worship based on an internal connection to God.

Comment: @DanFefferman-Coud it be that the use of "two phrases", *a time is coming*, * and now is*, would refer to the present  realization (at the well) that God was interested in heart-felt worship, **and** that there would definitely be a transition required in the future because the Temple worship was going to be entirely destroyed?  She, and other disciples, ought to get used to *spiritual * worship because both Mt. Gerizim and Mt. Zion were no longer to have any Temple standing in which to practice external ceremonies!

Comment: @DanFefferman Synagogues existed even in Jesus's time, so to say Jews found other ways of worship is inaccurate. The context of the Temple clearly includes sacrifices. Jesus's expansion of worship doesn't negate the context of the woman's question.